# Is it possible and if so how to clear localStorage with RobotFramework?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I've seen [doc's](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Click%20Link) for robotframework and i do not see posibility to clear local storage.

Basically I want to have test that sets some coockies with `Switch To` methodes.

```
Test Button Visibility For Administrator
    Switch To Administrator
    Go To Page    ${VIEW}
    Wait Until Page Contains    ${BUTTON}

Test Button Visibility for User
    Switch To User
    Go To Page    ${VIEW}
    Wait Until Page Does Not Contain    ${BUTTON}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a Selenium/SeleniumLibrary method for doing that (yet?), but localStorage is manipulated through JS. Here's a call to remove a specific key in it:

```
Execute Javascript      window.localStorage.removeItem('your_key_name');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Execute JavaScript command to clear the localStorage, which basically will run the command in the browser console:

```
 Execute JavaScript localStorage.clear();
```

More options here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_clear.asp